# Does there exist an $A$ and $\mathfrak{su}(2) \subset B$  such that $\mathfrak{su}(3) \simeq A \otimes B$

Tags: lie-algebras

I'm in the middle of trying to prove something at the moment and am looking for a decomposition of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ into a tensor product of some algebra $A$, and another $B$ containing $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, or some such result. Does anyone know of anything?

Comment: Does looking at the dimensions give you any information?

Comment: Best. Title. Ever.  You realize that it's unreadable, right?

Comment:  This is one of those questions where I wish the poster had said how they came across the question, since I simply can't imagine how it happened. What question about $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ could possibly be hard enough to justify all of this?

Comment: I was looking for an embedding of the coordinate ring of $SU(2)$  into the coordinate ring of $SU(3)$, and thought I find one using a dual map

Comment: ... where by embedding I mean linear not multiplicative.

Comment: FIIW, my comment above refers to an old, rather different version of the question. @Dyke: it tends to be not a good idea to change questions like that...

Comment: What does FIIW mean, Mariano ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathfrak{su}(3)$ cannot be decomposed as a tensor product, since there are no nonabelian simple Lie algebras of dimension 4, 2 or 1 (thus, any 8-d Lie algebra which is a tensor product has a proper ideal, which $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ doesn't).

Answer (score 5):

$\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is contained in $\mathfrak{su}(3)$, so you can take $A=k$ and $B=\mathfrak{su}(3)$ to answer the question in your title.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such *nontrivial* algebra, because $\dim \mathfrak{su}(2) = 3$ and $\dim \mathfrak{su}(3) = 8$.

As Mariano pointed out (and I missed), considering $\mathfrak{su}(2) \subset \mathfrak{su}(3)$ works trivially.

Comment: Could there be an embedding of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ into some four dimensional algebra $B$ such that $\mathfrak{su}(3) \simeq A \otimes B$?

Comment: See Mariano's answer.

Comment: Now I realize that I didn't misread the original version of the question...